# linking pic previews to posts

Tags: linking

This site is a twentytwelve child theme, and it's located at www.travelwithcastle.com

I'd like to link the pictures on the post previews (on the homepage) to the actual post -- right now when i click the picture, it is not linked. Only the title text is linked. I like that, and I'd like to also link the picture preview. Does anyone know how i can do this?

My guess is that it has to do with how i code the permalink in the content.php file, though I couldn't swear by that. To that end, here is my content.php code as it currently looks.

```
<?php
/**
 * The default template for displaying content. Used for both single and index/archive/search.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Twenty_Twelve
 * @since Twenty Twelve 1.0
 */
?>

    <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
        <?php if ( is_sticky() && is_home() && ! is_paged() ) : ?>
        <div class="featured-post">
            <?php _e( 'Featured post', 'twentytwelve' ); ?>
        </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <header class="entry-header">
            <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
            <?php if ( is_single() ) : ?>
            <h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
            <?php else : ?>
            <h1 class="entry-title">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( sprintf( __( 'Permalink to %s', 'twentytwelve' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ) ); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a> <br><?php the_date(); ?>
            </h1>
            <?php endif; // is_single() ?>
            <?php if ( comments_open() ) : ?>
                <div class="comments-link">
                    <?php comments_popup_link( '<span class="leave-reply">' . __( 'Leave a reply', 'twentytwelve' ) . '</span>', __( '1 Reply', 'twentytwelve' ), __( '% Replies', 'twentytwelve' ) ); ?>
                </div><!-- .comments-link -->
            <?php endif; // comments_open() ?>
        </header><!-- .entry-header -->

<?php if ( is_search() || is_home() ) : // Display Excerpts for Search and Homepage ?>

        <?php else : ?>
        <div class="entry-content">
            <?php the_content( __( 'Continue reading <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', 'twentytwelve' ) ); ?>
            <?php wp_link_pages( array( 'before' => '<div class="page-links">' . __( 'Pages:', 'twentytwelve' ), 'after' => '</div>' ) ); ?>
        </div><!-- .entry-content -->
        <?php endif; ?>


            <?php if ( is_singular() && get_the_author_meta( 'description' ) && is_multi_author() ) : // If a user has filled out their description and this is a multi-author blog, show a bio on their entries. ?>
                <div class="author-info">
                    <div class="author-avatar">
                        <?php echo get_avatar( get_the_author_meta( 'user_email' ), apply_filters( 'twentytwelve_author_bio_avatar_size', 68 ) ); ?>
                    </div><!-- .author-avatar -->
                    <div class="author-description">
                        <h2><?php printf( __( 'About %s', 'twentytwelve' ), get_the_author() ); ?></h2>
                        <p><?php the_author_meta( 'description' ); ?></p>
                        <div class="author-link">
                            <a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) ) ); ?>" rel="author">
                                <?php printf( __( 'View all posts by %s <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', 'twentytwelve' ), get_the_author() ); ?>
                            </a>
                        </div><!-- .author-link -->
                    </div><!-- .author-description -->
                </div><!-- .author-info -->
            <?php endif; ?>
        </footer><!-- .entry-meta -->
    </article><!-- #post -->
```

Comment: `the_post_thumbnail()` is what calls the image. It needs to be wrapped in a link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this line

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
```

with

```
<?php 
echo '<a href="' . get_permalink() . '">';
the_post_thumbnail(); 
echo '</a>';
?>
```

You want to use [get_permalink()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_permalink) to turn that image into a link.

Comment: thank you both for your information. i ended up adding a filter to functions.php which i found here after googling based on both replies http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail i would paste the code but it looks funky in the comment. so appreciate your assistance!

Comment: You could post it as an answer if you want, that way others could see the solution you adopted.

Comment: i ended up going with your code after all @ghosttoast. the functions.php filter i tried from codex worked for a brief while, and then i got an error with reference to my header. thanks so much - the code your shared is workin'